# How to send RGB565 over HTTP request from esp32

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I am working on ESP32-S2-Kaluga kit. I am trying to send the image captured to cloud through a POST request. I have been using ESP IDF to work. I successfully made a POST request, but with a basic JSON data. I have been trying the following code to get an RGB565 image.

```
camera_fb_t *pic = esp_camera_fb_get();
```

How can I convert this to UTF-8 and to put it in json data for POST request?

Comment: If you have the option you're best off just posting it as a file and not embedding it in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to convert it to base64 with `mbedtls_base64_encode`.